# Comovalidar valores desde aplicacion .net mvc5 & bootsrap a sql?

Tags: sql, .net, login

Soy nuevo en esto. Estoy haciendo un login en .net mvc5 con bootsrap, ya hice mi conexion con sql, solo quiero saber como tomar los valores que inserten en "nombre" y "contraseña" en sql al presionar el boton de "iniciar sesión".

```
    <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <!--  <center><label for="ejemplo_email_1">Nombre</label></center> -->
        <center><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuariotxt" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre"></center>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--   <center><label for="ejemplo_password_1">Contraseña</label></center> -->
        <center><input type="password" class="form-control" id="contraseñatxt" placeholder="Contraseña"></center> 
    </div>

    <!-- Botón normal -->
    <center> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar sesión</button> </center>

    <br />
```

Comment: Este workshop te dará una mano con ASP.net MVC 5 :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: ¿En tu login vas a insertar?, no debería ser validar. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta e incluir que tienes avanzado (indicas que ya hiciste la conexión).